# Google benchmark with command line args. Writing my own main function?

Tags: c++, benchmarking, microbenchmark, google-benchmark

I have a code that goes something like:

```
...
void benchMark(benchmark::State& state){
    maxCapacity = state.range(0);
    // set up some stuff
    for (auto _ : state){
        // time this code
    }
}

BENCHMARK(benchMark)->DenseRange(2, 10, 1);
BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

I want to change it to something like:

```
...
void benchMark(benchmark::State& state){
    maxCapacity = state.range(0);
    // set up some stuff
    for (auto _ : state){
        // time this code
    }
}

int main(){
    BENCHMARK(benchMark)->DenseRange(2, 10, 1);
}
```

I'm doing this just so that I can provide command line argument support to the code later. Now this code compiles successfully, but I don't get any output at all. The code doesn't even run I guess. The first code takes like 5 mins to complete, but the second one completes execution almost instantly. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be great. Thanks..

**EDIT:**

Since I can't share the full code, here's a minimum reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
using namespace std;

void pointQuery(int maxCapacity){
    long sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<100000*maxCapacity; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<100000*maxCapacity; j++)
            sum--;
        sum+=i;
    }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
}

void benchMark(benchmark::State& state){
    int maxCapacity = state.range(0);
    for (auto _ : state)
        pointQuery(maxCapacity);
}

BENCHMARK(benchMark)->DenseRange(2, 10, 1);
BENCHMARK_MAIN();
// int main(){
//     BENCHMARK(benchMark)->DenseRange(2, 10, 1);
// }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you just copy the contents of the BENCHMARK_MAIN macro to your test file it should work:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    BENCHMARK(benchMark)->DenseRange(2, 10, 1);

    //these entries are from BENCHMARK_MAIN
    ::benchmark::Initialize(&argc, argv);
    if (::benchmark::ReportUnrecognizedArguments(argc, argv)) return 1;
    ::benchmark::RunSpecifiedBenchmarks();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://github.com/google/benchmark) suggest using `benchmark::RegisterBenchmark`:

> Unlike the `BENCHMARK` registration macros, which can only be used at the global scope, the `RegisterBenchmark` can be called anywhere. This allows for benchmark tests to be registered programmatically. ... For Example:

```
auto BM_test = [](benchmark::State& st, auto Inputs) { /* ... */ };

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  for (auto& test_input : { /* ... */ })
      benchmark::RegisterBenchmark(test_input.name(), BM_test, test_input);
  benchmark::Initialize(&argc, argv);
  benchmark::RunSpecifiedBenchmarks();
}
```